# Chartkiq Line Graph plotting X-axis values differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, linegraph, chartkick

I am using the `gem 'chartkiq'` for plotting graphs in my Rails App.
It is working fine with bar and column types, not with line graph.

```
        <%= line_chart array_of_values %>
        array_ofvalues = [{:name=>"Last Year Net Sales", :data=>[[0, 1110.0],1,6450.0],[2, 13234.0], [3, 11234.0]]}, {:name=>"This Year Target Net Sales", :data=>[[0, 12000.0], [1, 5678.0], [2, 12222.0], [3, 12345.0]]}, {:name=>"This Year Net Sales", :data=>[[0, 1110.0], [1, 6450.0], [2, 13234.0], [3, 11234.0]]}]
```

**Here, 0,1,2 and 3 are the expected values on X-axis, but what is shown on the x-axis is '5:30:00 AM 5:30:00 AM 5:30:01 AM 5:30:01 AM 5:30:02 AM 5:30:02 AM 5:30:03 AM'**

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chartkick does not support discrete values for line charts at the moment.

https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/38

Comment: Exactly, I have given date values and it is working fine now. Thank you Andrew. Between, I would like to know whether there is a way to get y values(dots) plotted exactly above x axis dates.